# List not printing all .text values using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I've been using selenium recently and decided to pull some values into a list using the following:

```
Values = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='main-col']//li[@class='test-item test-item--favourites']")
```

The values are all stored as expected. Though when I use for example:

```
for i in range (len(Values)):
    print(Values[i].text)
    i+=1
```

The code runs up to about the 50th index in the list and outputs the details, but after this its blank. I can run:

```
print(values[50])
```

It will output but .text gives me nothing.

Im using pYcharm for the development and looked into the variables at this stage. I can see that once I click on the variable it states 'collecting variable data' and after this I can then output some more of the variables in the list.

Is there a way I can force selenium to collect all the variable data so I can loop through each index in the list and store it in the .text format or is there a better alternative/method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

If the `.text` is blank that means that there is no text between `CSS Selector`. To get an `attribute` out of a `CSS Selector` you have to use the `get_attribute()` function. Inside the `()` you place a `string` which is the name of an attribute which value you are looking for. for example

```
print(i.get_attribute('class'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are able to extract the *text* till the 50th index as `find_elements_by_xpath()` was able to identify 50 odd elements as per your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

---

### Solution

To collect all the desired elements using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.main-col li.test-item.test-item--favourites")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-col']//li[@class='test-item test-item--favourites']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I am facing the same issue and your answer does not address the problem. InnerHTML gives the whole list, but .text is empty for elements with a big index.